# I want to eliminate all of these case statements (too messy)

Tags: c#, button, case

I am writing a test program which returns a string "P3-PASS" or "P3-FAIL. In all there are 12 possible tests, P3 to P14 ("P3-FAIL" to "P14-PASS").

I have a button "All_Tests" which calls each test 1 by 1, and the associated button changes colour based on the result.

Ideally I want to do something like PageNum.Background = Brushes.Red, but I can't do this because I can't use a string to access the button. Hence the case statements below. Is there a way to simplify this, because it looks awful. OR is there a way to access the relevant button using a string, or similar. Many Thanks

```
int PageNum = Int32.Parse(PageTstName);

switch (PageNum)
{
    case 3:
        if (TstResult == "PASS")
        {
            Pg3.Background = Brushes.SeaGreen;
            Pg3.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        }
        else // TstResult is "FAIL"
        {
            Pg3.Background = Brushes.Red;
            Pg3.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        }
        break;

    case 4:
        if (TstResult == "PASS")
        {
            Pg4.Background = Brushes.SeaGreen;
            Pg4.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        }
        else // TstResult is "FAIL"
        {
            Pg4.Background = Brushes.Red;
            Pg4.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        }
        break;

    case 5: .....etc
```

Comment: What framework are you on? Winforms?

Comment: No, I am using WPF, .NET framework 4.8,  I should have mentioned that in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary that maps the numbers to the controls, e.g.

```
var controlsByPageNum = new Dictionary<int, Button>() 
{
  { 3, Pg3 },
  { 4, Pg4 },
  { 5, Pg5 },
  // ...
}
```

When receiving the test results, you can get the control like this:

```
int PageNum = Int32.Parse(PageTstName);
var btn = controlsByPageNum[PageNum];
if (TstResult == "PASS")
{
  btn.Background = Brushes.SeaGreen;
  btn.Foreground = Brushes.White;
}
else // TstResult is "FAIL"
{
  btn.Background = Brushes.Red;
  btn.Foreground = Brushes.White;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant Markus, this is just what I needed (only my first C# program) -- Many Thanks

Comment: @MarkStevens you're welcome. Have a great C# journey :-)

Comment: I want to use this Dictionary in 1 other place within my program, it's local at the moment, is there a way to make it global, or is that frowned upon. How could I make it global?

Comment: It would be prefereable to make it global, in this specific case it might not be too easy because you need to add the buttons to the dictionary. The buttons are local to the form, hence this won't work. However, if you need the dictionary on the same form, you can initialize it in your form's constructor after `InitializeComponent` and store it in a class-level field. @MarkStevens

Comment: Many Thanks once again Markus - much appreciated, not written any classes yet, so I will keep Dictionary local until I can work that out.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method to apply your colors:

```
private static void ApplyColors(Control control, Brush background, Brush foreground)
{
    control.Background = background;
    control.Foreground = foreground;
}
```

And a dictionary to map each case:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Action> dict = 
    new Dictionary<string, Action>();
```

Now, in your constructor, fill the dictionary:

```
dict[$"3~PASS"] = () => ApplyColors(Pg3, Brushes.SeaGreen, Brushes.White);
dict[$"3~FAIL"] = () => ApplyColors(Pg3, Brushes.Red, Brushes.White);
dict[$"4~PASS"] = () => ApplyColors(Pg4, Brushes.SeaGreen, Brushes.White);
dict[$"4~FAIL"] = () => ApplyColors(Pg4, Brushes.Red, Brushes.White);
```

Here, for each page and result, you define the action to execute. With this, now you can manage your current switch in this way:

```
var key = $"{PageTstName}~{TstResult}";
if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out Action action))
{
    action();
}
else
{
    // A non mapped case...
}
```